# using windows event viewer to log from net core console application

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, console

I have c# net core 3.1 console app.
How to get log messages to windows event viewer?
Now I have this, and it not work...

```
            services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddFilter<EventLogLoggerProvider>(level => level >= LogLevel.Warning))
                .Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options => options.MinLevel = LogLevel.Warning)
                .AddTransient<Program>();
...
            _serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider(true);
```

If I try to use `configure.AddConsole()` instead `configure.AddFilter<EventLogLoggerProvider>` It work perfectly and give me a log data in Console window.
Thank you!

Comment: yes, ``{"Logging":{"LogLevel":{"Default":"Warning","Microsoft":"Warning"}}}``